# page-break-before not working in firefox browser when printing a webpage in asp.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <table id="tbtest" style="page-break-before:always;">
               <tr>
                   <td> Dummy Text</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The above code breaks the page perfectly in google chrome, but does not seems to work in firefox browser, can anybody has any solution that how should i insert page break in firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Look what I have found in FF docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fpage-break-before

> This properties applies to block elements that generate a box. It
>   won't apply on an empty  that won't generate a box.

**1 -** Try to check if placing "display:block;" in your element works:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" style="display:block;">

<table id="tbtest" style="page-break-before:always;display:block;">
```

if you have an element before these, try to set `display:block` as well

**2 -** I don't have a Firefox browser to test right know, but I used to place a `<p>` before the element and it worked, try this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <p>
               <table id="tbtest" style="page-break-before:always;">
                   <tr>
                       <td> Dummy Text</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </p>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

or this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <p></p>
           <table id="tbtest" style="page-break-before:always;">
               <tr>
                   <td> Dummy Text</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Try both tips, but I'm not 100% sure if some will work because I can't test right now, but at least you know the problem from the official docs and have some stuff to try to work. I hope that helps.